# 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, wcf, api

No sure what I am missing but for some reason WCf keeps throwing this error at me.

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

My service

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[UserAccessRoleValidatorAspect(Access = Otive.Subscriptions.UserAccessType.Install)]
public class PaymentProcessPublic : BaseService,IPaymentProcessPublic
{
    private PaymentProcessorInvoiceService PaymentProcessorInvoiceService = 
        new  PaymentProcessorInvoiceService(ConnectionManager.GetConnectionInfo(Otive.Consts.TenantId));

    public GetQuickInvoiceInfoResponse GetInvoiceQuickInfo (GetQuickInvoiceInfoRequest Request)
    {
        GetQuickInvoiceInfoResponse Response = new GetQuickInvoiceInfoResponse();

        Response.PaymentProcessorInvoiceInfo = this.Converter.Convert( PaymentProcessorInvoiceService.GetPaymentProcessorInvoiceInfo(Guid.Parse(Request.PaymentKey)));

        return Response;
    }
}
```

My interface

```
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    Method = "*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[OperationContract]
GetQuickInvoiceInfoResponse GetInvoiceQuickInfo(GetQuickInvoiceInfoRequest Request);
```

Request Header
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Request Payload
{PaymentKey: "A4F5E417-4938-4BA6-9E4C-FEC4C6499B28"}

Server Request Object

```
public class GetQuickInvoiceInfoRequest
{
    public string PaymentKey { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issues was caused by not having access to the requested resource. That message was very misleading.